# How to detect which parallel process ends first in Linux?

Tags: performance, bash, time, command-line, parallel-processing

I have 2 programs: `known` and `unknown` . I know the output of the `known` program (which is constant), but I don't know the output of the `unknown` program (which could be the same as `known` in some cases). I want to run them parallel on a Linux machine so that both of them get the same CPU power. I found several solutions for this, but the problem I am facing is detecting which program ends first.

I tried `echo $(./known & ./unknown)` which works fine except that there is no way for me to detect which ended first if both outputs are the same.

I also tried `echo $(./known & time ./unknown > /dev/null)` but for some reason the output of the `time` command is always printed before the `known` command even though I deliberately made `unknown` slower than `known` (so it was supposed to be the other way around). The output is something like this:

```
echo $(./known & time ./unknown >/dev/null)

real    0m2.054s
user    0m3.072s
sys     0m0.000s
b
```

Here, 'b' is the output of the `known` command which I expected to be printed first because it is the faster program.

So any idea how I can detect which process ends first?

Comment: `echo $(./known&&echo "known first" & ./unknown&&echo "unknown first")`

Comment: @JID Thanks, but one problem. Something like this pops up: `[1] 23191`. How do I get rid of that?

Comment: @JID Also, for some reason, the output of the one which ends later is displayed in the command typing line (user@pc:~$...) and after pressing <Enter> it shows some other unwanted text like `[1]+  Done `. This is messy :(

Comment: Don't run background commands then...

Comment: @JID Sorry, I didn't get that. Is there a way to do this on the foreground?

Comment: Run them from a script and you won't get job control telling you stuff

Comment: @JID Thanks for the idea. But I just found a solution to directly do them from the command line :) Please see my answer.

Comment: Whatever works for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to post my own answer, but I just found a solution. This works:

`echo $(./known & echo x$(./unknown))`

Here, 'x' is what differentiates the two outputs, so even if they are the same, I know which one was printed first.

Please feel free to answer or comment if you have a better solution. Thanks.

Comment: [Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by trapping `kill` signals as below.

Let's say there's a `known.sh` script

```
sleep 4
d=$(date '+%H:%M:%S')
echo "known process $d [parent PID: $1]"
kill -SIGUSR1 $1
```

An `unknown.sh` script

```
sleep 1
d=$(date '+%H:%M:%S')
echo "unknown process $d [parent PID: $1]"
kill -SIGUSR2 $1
```

Finally, a `master.sh` script that will wait for SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 signals

```
trap 'echo "$k ended"' SIGUSR1 SIGUSR2

echo "I'm the master [PID $$]"
k=$(time ./unknown.sh $$ &)
k=$(time ./known.sh $$ &)
sleep 5
```

Output of `master.sh` will be

```
I'm the master [PID 3205]

real    0m1.005s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.001s
unknown process 00:53:57 [parent PID: 3205] ended

real    0m4.004s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.001s
known process 00:54:01 [parent PID: 3205] ended
```